# QT Progressbar Centering

Tags: qt, progress-bar

I am trying to center my progressbar to my screen center, but it is always on the top left...
Here is the code:

```
QProgressBar vBar;
vBar.setWindowFlags(Qt::FramelessWindowHint);
vBar.setRange(0,9);
vBar.setAlignment(Qt::AlignCenter);
vBar.show();
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  vBar.setvalue(i);
}
```

Comment: And where is the code that tries to change its position?

Comment: vBar.setAlignment(Qt::AlignCenter);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`vBar.setAlignment()` sets the alignment of the progress bar text (the percentage) inside the progress bar, not the position of the progress bar itself. To center the progress bar on the screen, you need to use something like

```
vBar.show();
vBar.move((QApplication::desktop()->width() - vBar.width() ) / 2,
          (QApplication::desktop()->height() - vBar.height() ) / 2);
```

Comment: Yes, this is what I did already, but I thought that there will be maybe a more elegant solution... Thanks anyway